# Function to align elements horizontally

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting, header-footer

I've found this [resume template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/recreating-business-insiders-cv-of-marissa-mayer/gtqfpbwncfvp) on Overleaf, and I'd like to make some tweaks on how the header information is positioned. Originally, that's how the resume header looks like:

[image: Original Header]

The original `makecvheader` function looks like this:

```latex
\newcommand{\makecvheader}{%
  \begingroup
    \altacv@left@photos\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\altacv@photos@width}%
    \raggedright%
    {\namefont\color{name}\MakeUppercase{\@name}\par}
    \medskip
    {\taglinefont\color{tagline}\@tagline\par}
    \medskip
    {\personalinfofont\@personalinfo\par}
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \altacv@right@photos\par%
  \endgroup\medskip
}
```

But I want all the personal information disposed in lines bellow the tagline to be stacked to the right. So I thought that if I created a second `minipage` inside the group would be enough. But that is what I've got:

[image: Modified Header]

And here is the modifications I've made:

```latex
\newcommand{\makecvheader}{%
  \begingroup
    \altacv@left@photos%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-\altacv@photos@width}%
    \raggedright%
    {\namefont\color{name}\MakeUppercase{\@name}\par}
    \medskip
    {\taglinefont\color{tagline}\MakeUppercase{\@tagline}}
    \medskip
    \end{minipage}%
    \begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\altacv@photos@width}%
    \raggedleft%
    {\personalinfofont\@personalinfo\par}
    \end{minipage}
  \endgroup\medskip
}
```

And here is what I wanted it to look like:
[image: Desired Positioning]

So what's the best way to achieve this? Hope any of you can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you clarify what the problem is with your modifications, and what the desirable final header would look like?

Comment: @MahmoudElfar, the personal info stack gets clipped because it doesn't stick inside the page boundaries. I added how I wish it to look like now.

Answer (score 1):

The reason why it gets clipped is that the first minipage width (`\dimexpr\linewidth-\altacv@photos@width`) spans the whole linewidth minus the picture width.

Here is a quick-and-dirty solution.

```
\newcommand{\makecvheader}{%
  \begingroup
    \altacv@left@photos%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}%
    {\namefont\color{name}\MakeUppercase{\@name}\par}
    \medskip
    {\taglinefont\color{tagline}\@tagline\par}
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{3cm}%
    \raggedright%
    {\personalinfofont\@personalinfo\par}%
    \end{minipage}\hfill%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\altacv@photos@width}
        \strut\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\newline\altacv@right@photos\par%
    \end{minipage}
  \endgroup\medskip
}
```

You also don't have to modify the cls file by using `renewcommand` and wrapping the code above between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

[image]

PS: Quick because it takes the least time. Dirty because you have to fine-tune the minipage widths according to the contents, it is not the best way to align contents, and will break if you decide to use different options (like the option to put the picture to the left).